# greenworks and node webkit not working with steam overlay

Tags: javascript, html, node-webkit, steam

I am working on a game in node webkit and greenworks that i want to release on steam soon, everything was fine until I added it to steam as a non-steam game just to see how the overlay would look and it just will not come up. I read up on the steam overlay and apparently it only supports  games with directx and opengl, my game does not use either of those and it also doesn't use webgl. How do I get the steam overlay to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you start the game from outside Steam (as a non-steam game) you need to add a `steam_appid.txt` file with your (or a test) [app id](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3729-WFJZ-4175) so that Steam knows that this is a *steam game*.

I can definitely confirm that the overlay should work for html5 games.

For more trouble shooting tips please check out the updated [greenworks documentation](https://github.com/greenheartgames/greenworks).